# Why does this td style only apply to one of these tables?

Tags: html, css

I have some HTML tables which are styled like this.

```
td
{
    width: 20em;
    height: 2ex;
}
```

Please see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/40t3nzoh/) for full details. This source passes the W3 validator with no errors or warnings.

There are three tables in the page. Only the second one seems to have this style applied. Why is this?

<del>Here's how it renders in Firefox 42.0 on Ubuntu.</del>

EDIT: Incorporating Pangloss's suggestion gives me a version which works [in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hu2cqkk9/) but *not* as a standalone web page.

Here's how the latest version renders in JSFiddle

[image]

And here's how it renders as a standalone web page with the same source in the same browser. In this version the first and second tables are fine but the second one has cells too wide. How the heck is *this* happening?

[image]

Comment: Why are you using `ex` units? What about the styling do you feel isn't being applied?

Comment: IIRC `em` are used for font sizing - same for `ex`.

Comment: What's happening is the width of the window is not large enough and it is constraining the table width. If I increase the body width to an obscene number (10000px), it renders as expected. [**Updated JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/40t3nzoh/5/). Consider using more rows and less columns.

Comment: Just dropping by to say I really like your grey palette.

Comment: Hang on, the width of the window shouldn't be constraining it because it scrolls horizontally, right?

Comment: @spraff What happens is that the window width will try to constrain the body width to be the same as itself. When your content will no longer fit within that width, the window will begin to scroll. In order to force it to a certain width, you have to define the width of your elements manually. Table cells are a bit funny in this way though, as the width of the table itself will override the width of its cells. Since the width of the table automatically reverts to 100% of the window size, its contents are constrained to 100% of the window size. The only reason they even stretch any wider...

Comment: than that is because, by default, word wrapping is set to break on new words, rather than breaking words themselves. So the width of the window is set to the widest string of words that appears in your table...if that makes sense. The way to fix it? set the table width, the body width, etc. Pangloss's solution will also work here.

Comment: Fixing the table layout makes the table's width dependent on it's contents, rather than its contents' width being dependent on the width of the table, which is why that solution works.

Comment: @spraff Do you have a link to the standalone page where this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's only seems like it because the choice of 20em and 2ex is "unlucky" or the table is too big (e.g. the first one).

Starting with the height of 2ex. It is just chosen too small, it is about the height of the letters. Try changing it to 1em, you see no difference, but if you change it to 3em you will notice it, because now it is bigger then the letters size.
Same applies for the first table, since it is several lines big and it can't go any smaller the 2em can't be applied.

Now regarding the 20em.
It feels like it only applies to the 2nd table, because it is the only one so small that the browser actually has room to expand the table.
You can see a huge difference if you take the first and third table and remove every single table data (td) except for, let's say two.

Here your shortened 3rd table to save some work:

```html
<table><tbody>
<tr>
 <td style="background:#351e1c">Kurotobi</td><td style="background:#374231">Sensaimidori</td></tr>
<tr>
 <td style="background:#614e6e">Futaai</td><td style="background:#6b9362">Wakatake-iro</td></tr>
<tr>
 <td style="background:#913228">Benitobi</td><td style="background:#97645a">Umenezumi</td></tr>
<tr>
 <td style="background:#c3272b">Akabeni</td><td style="background:#c57f2e">Kuwazome</td></tr>
<tr>
 <td style="background:#ffa631">Tamago-iro</td><td style="background:#ffb94e">Hanaba-iro</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

In addition to the first table. The browser again tries to get all the data on the screen without influencing the content (for example letting it overlap).
Now he does that and used all the space he has to display the tables content and decides to just cut of the rest of the space you told him to add (with the 20em).
In case you have 2 screens try pulling the browser window across both of them, you will notice that the browser uses more and more space until he has enough to display the 20em as well.

Hope I could help!
(Btw take a look at external css, helps a lot to keep the code clean 
[Link how to include a css file externally](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp) :)

Answer (score 1):

Alright, the table is trying to fit "too much" in a "too small" of space, you need to make the space bigger, I am making the "body" bigger for this example.

To start, set the font-size to 16px, collapsed the borders on the cells and remove the margins on the body. To make the math easy to understand.

Since `em` is a relative size to the font. take 16 * 20 (for 20 em) = 320.

Now multiple 320 * 29 (the amount of cells in the table with the most cells) = 9280px

Now you know the minimum width of the body needs to be at least 9280px.

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/40t3nzoh/7/